# Deploy an app which requires disk storage to Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I am trying to migrate an old app to Azure. Let's call the app `OAP`. OAP was currently deployed locally on a typical server with Windows Server 2016.

When the user is using OAP, he may upload files to the system via a browser.

On the OAP server side, written by C#, it saves the file to the local disk. The saving location is a configurable setting for OAP. It values `F:\OAPStorage` now.

Now I need to deploy the app which requires disk storage to Azure app service. I understand that Azure app service provides some space for running an App. But what if the app scales?

I understand the best practice is to use `Azure Blob Storage`. But refactor the old app `OAP` is not possible. I have to provide it file storage to save user uploaded files. Is it okay to save it just on the disk which app runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution finally.

In the Web App, under Application Settings, you will find Mount storage (Preview) section where you can mount Storage account. Works like a charm. In Linux Web Apps and Windows Containers Web Apps only.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/09/24/announcing-bring-your-own-storage-to-app-service/

But this is only a preview feature and do not support Windows Web Apps.

Comment: Non Containerized Windows Apps are now *supported - *in preview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=code-windows

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the App Service Plan you pick.  Each plan has different amounts of storage.

- Free and Shared = 1GB
- Basic = 10GB
- Standard = 50GB
- Premium = 250GB
- Isolated = 1TB

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

You can access this storage space on the following directories <sup>[[Ref](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system)]</sup>

- `%HOME%` or `\home\` for Linux - For persistent storage
- `%SYSTEMDRIVE%` - For accessing the drive. It usually point to `D:` drive in Windows Containers.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use Azure App to host your website, the storage is all depending on the Service Plan, if you want more storage you have to scale up your tier.Here is the [pricing for Windows Service Plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/).

If you don't need the Azure Features , you could also choose Azure VM to deploy your site.And Azure VM support to add disks, there are HDD disks and SSD disks for choice.And here is the [pricing for Managed Disks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/).If you want to use Azure VM, here is the [VM charges](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/).

Comment: I am not considering Azure virtual machines. I am wondering what if my app scales? Will my files be accessed by all instances?